# How can I catch a firebase auth error with firebase admin

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have the following try catch

```
try {
  user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(inputEmail);
} catch (error) {
  if(error.code !== "auth/user-not-found") throw new Error("authentication failed");
}
```

But I get an an error saying

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

On error.code

This code was working perfectly fine before. How can this be solved?

I found the this

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.FirebaseError

but I do not know where I can import it from.

[image]

I tried to asign any as type
[image]

And I tried to check if the error was a instance of Error which says

```
Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you get that error? Can you share a screenshot of it with stack trace? Also you are looking at Firebase JS SDKs docs. [Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) to see Firebase Admin Auth errors.

Comment: It is a vscode error popup. I did see those errors and I am trying to check for it. But the error is of type unknown and thus has no code property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error simply says that type of `error` is unknown.

```ts
try {
  // ...
} catch (error: unknown) {
  // unknown --> ^^^
}
```

If you are using `Typescript 4.4` then you can use [--useUnknownInCatchVariables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables) flag which changes the default type of catch clause variables from `any` to `unknown`.

Then you set up [User defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to specify type for the error that is being thrown. You can import `FirebaseError` from `@firebase/util` as in this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/403).

```ts
import { FirebaseError } from '@firebase/util';

try {
  // ...
} catch (error: unknown) {
  if (error instanceof FirebaseError) {
     console.error(error.code)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it will throw an error during deployment saying 

`Catch clause variable cannot have a type annotation.`

Comment: The import was what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it with this:

```js
try {
  user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(inputEmail);
} catch (error:unknown) {
  
  if (error instanceof Error) {
      if(error.code !== "auth/user-not-found") throw new Error("authentication failed");
  
  }
}
```

Pls check this [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#unknown-on-catch-clause-bindings) about it.

Comment: It does not seem to work, I get the same error. I added a screenshot.